# WCF service in windows process activation service (WAS)

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I was reading WCF .NET 4 faq. I'm not sure with the answer for the following question.
Q: A wcf client is needed for the WCF service hosted within WAS. The service is configured as below:

```
<service name="abc">
<endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" contract="IMainService">
</service>
```

The service is located at the URL `http://servername/wcfservice/abc.svc` Which config settings should be added to `system.serviceModel/client` element?

A:

```
<endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" contract="IMainService" address="net.tcp://servername/wcfservice/abc.svc"
```

Shouldn't the address in the `client` section start with `http`? or the service should be exposed with `net.tcp`? Or the binding in the service should be `http`? I need input from community. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the answer is correct. The server endpoint says it's a netTcpBinding so the client has to use a 'net.tcp://...' addess.

It does seems a little confusing. I presume that when they say 'The service is located at the URL http://...' they are referring to the metadata, which is typically published over http, even though the service itself is exposed via net.tcp. It could also be a typo.